# How to use other attribute types in classdiagrams in visio?

Tags: parameters, uml, visio, class-diagram

I have no idea where to ask, so I hope that some Visio specialists can help. I'm just making a class diagram but Visio seems to be very static and simple for method signatures.

All I wanted to add is a constructor with the following parameters:

```
public Position(LinkedList<T> apList, float x, float y);
```

That's what I want to add to Visio. All standard data types work fine but how do you insert other types? I don't know why the answer is so hard to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

on your left you will find the model explorer , If not view it then you will be able to see folders that contain C# datatypes , C++ datatypes...etc. Right click on any of then and add a new type .

Answer (score 0):

it seems that no one knows. well the only solution i found is to use ArgoUML. that's it!